# two segues coming from one view controller, prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, segue

Is there a way to have a different prepareForSegue's for different segues coming out the same view controller?

Because I have 2 segues coming out of one view, and there obviously are some workarounds, but I was wondering if it was possible to separate the prepareForSegues into 2 entirely separate methods depending on the segue called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use two different methods.
You can however call two different methods in a conditional statement like bellow:

You can check which segue was invoked:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addNewCheckListItem"]) {        
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showExistingCheckListItem"]) {
    }
}
```

But make sure you also set them an identifier from Interface Builder